# How can I sort a one (or two) dimensional array (multidimensional) based on one column?

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting, csv

I have an array of comma separated strings in an android project as follows:

```
1,orange,$5
2,apple,$6
3,banana,$8
```

I want to sort the array by a field, say by the 2nd field as *apple, banana, orange...*

What would be the best data structure or algorithm to handle this?

Comment: I prefer the title be "a one or two dimensional array"  as the two dimensional one is a bit complicated and I like the arrayList collection method better, and the array is collected in runtime and is not fixed.

Comment: Can anyone explain more about how the compareto method and how it is used? It looks complicated too compared with other language.

Comment: you got some advance?

Answer (score 1):

Sort your array with a custom comparator:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

class Fruits {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        final String[][] data = new String[][] {
                new String[] { "1", "orange", "$5" },
                new String[] { "2", "apple", "$6" },
                new String[] { "3", "banana", "$8" } };

        Arrays.sort(data, new Comparator<String[]>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(final String[] entry1, final String[] entry2) {
                final String fruit1 = entry1[1];
                final String fruit2 = entry2[1];
                return fruit1.compareTo(fruit2);
            }
        });

        for (final String[] s : data) {
            System.out.println(s[0] + " - " + s[1] + " - " + s[2]);
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
2 - apple - $6
3 - banana - $8
1 - orange - $5
```

You can read more in:

> http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html
>
> [How does this comparator work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23136998/3653989)

Comment: @user2911996 you got some advance?

Comment: can you make this a one dimensional one and the array not fixed, ie. pass the array to a function? Can anyone explain more about how the compareto method and how it is used? It looks complicated too compared with other language.

Comment: we can also pass the position of the comma separated strings so we can sort in any position and also accordingly to sort by number or by string. I am making it a resue-able function call.

Answer (score 0):

You should model the String values into a java bean like let's say Fruit. In that class you need to implement the `Comparable` interface in which you state the manner of how objects are compared. Create your objects using the newly create class and populate your objects into a list and after that, simply call Collections.sort() and you'll have your list sorted;

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use ArrayList collection for your data, it is easy to sort data. You just need to implement Compralable interface in your model class and inside compareTo method write the logic of sort. Use collection.sort() to sort the data.