# Rank students based on score

Tags: java, comparator

I would like to ask how do i achieve the following result by applying comparator to it:

Input:

4     //the number of student in this class list

Student1 200 //[name] [score]

Student2 200

Student3 100

Student4 300

Output:

Student1 2 //[name] [rank]

Student2 2

Student3 4

Student4 1

*student obtaining the same score will be at the same rank

`

```
public class Ranking {
    private void run() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = sc.nextInt();
        Student [] studentArray = new Student [number];

    for(int i=0;i<number;i++){
        String name = sc.next();
        int score = sc.nextInt();
        studentArray [i] = new Student(name, score, 0);
    }

    getRanks(number, studentArray);

    for(Student s: studentArray){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

public void getRanks(int number, Student [] studentArray){
    int ranking = 1;
    studentArray[0].setRank(ranking);
    for(int i = 1; i<number; i++){
        if(studentArray[i].getScore() != studentArray[i-1].getScore()){
            ranking ++;
            studentArray[i].setRank(ranking);
        }
    }
}
```

`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does this comparator work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23136998/how-does-this-comparator-work), and many other similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

Why not convert you array to a List and then run

```
Collections.sort(studentList, new Comparator<Student>() {
    public int compare(Student a, Student b) {
        return a.getScore() - b.getScore();
    }
});
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)

After that the index of any Student in that list would determine  it’s rank.

You may clean the rank by looping through the List and associate the rank to each Student directly, not incrementing it if the last score is equal to the current.

```
int lastScore = -1;
int rank = studentList.size() + 1;
for(Student s : studentList) {
    if(s.getScore() > lastScore) {
        rank—;
    }
    s.setRank(rank);
    lastScore = s.getScore();
}
```

UPDATE:
To set the rank according to the index of the Student in the List:

```
int lastScore = -1;
int rank = studentList.size() + 1;
int displayRank = rank;
for(Student s : studentList) {
    rank—;
    if(s.getScore() > lastScore) {
        displayRank = rank;
    }
    s.setRank(displayRank);
    lastScore = s.getScore();
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for the solution :) But for your solution, i am not being able to produce the desired output that are sorted based on the input order. Next, i've changed the question where there will be no rank 3 since there is two rank 2 and the next rank will straight to rank 4 instead of 3. will you be able to assist me with this?

Comment: What do you mean by „based on the Input order“? The Java Comparator is guaranteed to do a stable sort thus not flipping elements if they have the same comparision value (in this case not flipping Students if they have the same score)

Comment: Ahh. You want to output the students in initial order and not rank order. Try to not output the studentsList but to copy your input array to a new List (eg LinkedList so that the List is not backed by the array) and then do the sorting/ranking but output by looping through your initial array

Comment: *Edited* your solution works completely fine, however the output i got is Student3 1, Student1 2, Student2 2, Student4 4 while the answer that I want is that the output is printed based on the input order as shown: Student1 2, Student2 2, Student3 4, Student4 1

Comment: beside that, Student4 supposed to be on first rank since he got the highest score but your solution has made Student3 with lowest score the first rank :(

Comment: UPDATE: bugfixes that. Was starting at rank 1 but needed to start at last rank, because the comparator produced an ascending order

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Ranking {
    private void run() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number = sc.nextInt();
        Student [] studentArray = new Student [number];

    for(int i=0;i<number;i++){
        String name = sc.next();
        int score = sc.nextInt();
        studentArray [i] = new Student(name, score, 0);
    }

    getRanks(number, studentArray);

    for(Student s: studentArray){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}

public void getRanks(int number, Student [] studentArray){
    List<Student> studentList = Arrays.asList(studentArray);

    Comparator<Student> comparator = new Comparator<Student>() {
        public int compare(Student student1, Student student2) {
           // for descending order
            return student2.getScore() - student1.getScore(); 
        }
    };
    Collections.sort(studentList, comparator);

    int ranking = 1, displayRanking = 1;
    studentList.get(0).setRank(displayRanking);
    for(int i = 1; i<number; i++){
        ranking++;
        if(studentList.get(i).getScore() > studentList.get(i - 1).getScore()){
            displayRanking = ranking;
        }
        studentList.get(i).setRank(displayRanking);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<number; i++){
        int index = sortedList.indexOf(studentArray[i]);
        studentArray[i].setRank(sortedList.get(index).getRank);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the solution. But can i know where did you get the sortedArray ?

Comment: Sorry its sortedList (not sortedArray), I updated my answer.